# Postgres SQL Timezone conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I could appreciate a second pair of eyes on my Postgres syntax.

Database stores timestamp in `UTC`. I'm trying to convert from `UTC` to Eastern Daylight Time `EDT`, but the output is not accurate.

Here's my syntax:

```
SELECT
to_char(((timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'EDT'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
FROM table_name
```

Record TimeStamp:

```
09/10/2016 12:00
```

Query Output:

```
09/10/2016 16:00
```

Desired Output:

```
09/10/2016 08:00
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Use `timestamptz` instead of `timestamp`. They're both 8 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saying `AT TIMEZONE` twice is redundant since it will just convert from whatever the current timezone (which you suggest is UTC) to UTC then to EDT.

The fact that you feel the need to convert it to UTC tells me you're not storing it as a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`.  Check if this is the case.  If it is, that's likely your problem.  [From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html):

> If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's timezone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

Basically, if you don't specify, it assumes it's from your current timezone by default, not UTC.  It's possible you entered a UTC timestamp and it assumed it was EDT.

Comment: Thanks! removing the first `AT TIMEZONE` did the trick. Thanks again for the insight